# Sparse Collaborative Filtering

Tags: python, recommender-system

Does anyone know of any Python code examples for sparse collaborative filtering. Everything I can find revolves around using prebuilt packages (e.g. Mahout, GraphLab), but I'm learning to learn the programming of the algorithm itself.

Comment: Sparse Collaborative Filtering reminds me matrix factorization with sparsity enforcing regularization (l1-norm). Take a look at http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/StatLearnSparsity/ and the references therein.

Comment: In Python, you can do sparse modeling with the SPAMS toolbox http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/

Answer (score 1):

Here you can have examples of how to code recommendation systems algorithms in python
http://guidetodatamining.com/chapter-2

Comment: Document not found...

Comment: @StudentT http://guidetodatamining.com/chapter2/